# pythonでpandasをインポートできない

Tags: python, macos, pandas

Pythonの超初心者です。お力添えのほど何卒お願いいたします。

Pythonでcsvを読み込んで加工や分析みたいなことをしたいと思い、Python3.6とpycharmを入れました。

csv読み込みにはpandasだと記事で読んだので、まずpandasを入れてインポートしようとしたのですができず・・・具体的には以下の通りです。

ターミナルで `pip show pandas` と入れたら、以下が出てきたのでインストールはできているんだと思います。

```
Name: pandas Version: 0.22.0 
Summary: Powerful data structures fordata analysis, time series,and statistics
Home-page:http://pandas.pydata.org 
Author: The PyData Development Team
Author-email: pydata@googlegroups.com 
License: BSD 
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires: python-dateutil, numpy, pytz
```

しかし、pythonで `import pandas as pd` と入れても、エラーが表示されてしまいます。

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

ちなみにOSはmacOS High Sierra 10.13.3
pythonはpython3.6をインストールしてます。

お力添えのほど何卒お願いいたします。

Comment: `pip3 show pandas` の結果はどうなりますか？ Location を見るに、表示されているのは Python 2.x 系列の結果に見えます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip show pandasに対して、"Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages"を含む情報が表示されたのですから、
python 2.7なら import pandas が出来るけれど、python 3.xなら出来ない　という状況でしょう。

pythonとpandasに関連するファイルやフォルダー、環境変数などを全て(Python 2.Xのものも、Python 3.xのものも）削除してから、python3.6とpycharmをインストールし直してください。
その後で、pandasをインストールしてみてください。
そうすれば、Locationが Python/2.7の下という状況が改善するはずです。

Comment: 私も Python 2 系の環境が優先されていることが原因だと思うのですが、Mac 環境において Python 2 系をふっ飛ばしてしまっても依存関係的に困りはしないのでしょうか？　（Mac の環境に詳しくないのでよく分からないのです。）新規にインストールしたのが Python 3 と PyCharm のみだったということであれば、それまでにインストールした何かが Python 2 に依存しているのかなあ、と思い、強気な回答ができませんでした。

Comment: 返事ありがとうございます。仰る通りpython2環境でインストールしていたため、できなかったようでした。ターミナルでpip3～～とかってやるのではなく、Pycharm上でインストールしたら回りました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

Mac, Linuxでは、単に python, pip とコマンドを叩くと、python2.7が起動し、python2.7の方にパッケージがインストールされます。python3, pip3 とコマンドを叩けばPython3系が起動し、python3系の方にパッケージがインストールされます。現状では、python3系を使いたい場合はコマンドに3をつけましょう。

システムに標準でインストールされているpython2.7を削除してしまうのは、適切な方法とはいえません。公式マニュアルには以下のように記載されています。

> Apple が提供している Python のビルドは /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework と /usr/bin/python にそれぞれインストールされています。これらは Apple が管理しているものであり Apple やサードパーティのソフトウェアが使用するので、編集したり削除したりしてはいけません。