# import pandas as pdと入れて実行するとNo module named 'pandas'とエラーが出る

Tags: python, pandas

Python始めたての初心者です。わからない用語も多く悪戦苦闘しています。
タイトルの通り、`import pandas as pd` と実行すると `No module named 'pandas'` とエラーが出てしまいます。

「No module named 'pandas'」でGoogle検索をしたのですが、なかなかどうして対処法がわからず困っています。
お力添えくださいますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

**使用しているPC:**
macOS Big Sur 11.4

下記はターミナルにて `pip show pandas` と入れた際に出てきたものです。

```
Name: pandas
Version: 1.3.3
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: The Pandas Development Team
Author-email: pandas-dev@python.org
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /Users/odahomare/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: python-dateutil, numpy, pytz
Required-by:
```

Comment: 2系と3系の両方がインストールされているのでは？ そして2系のインタプリタを起動していたとか？ 或いは3系も多数インストールされていて、pandasの入っていない環境で起動していたとか？[macOS Big SurでPythonをはじめてみる](https://qiita.com/shiragamotohiro/items/b177a36ec72705c071dc)

Comment: `Location:` を見ると `Python 3.9` 対応の Pandas がインストールされている事が判ります。実行している Python 本体のバージョンはどうなっていますか？  [pythonでpandasをインポートできない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/42613) も参考にしてみて下さい。